# Python logging setLevel() not taking effect

Tags: python, logging, python-multiprocessing

I have a python program that utilizes multiprocessing to increase efficiency, and a function that creates a logger for each process. The logger function looks like this:

```
import logging
import os

def create_logger(app_name):
    """Create a logging interface"""
    # create a logger
    if logging in os.environ:
        logging_string = os.environ["logging"]
        if logging_string == "DEBUG":
            logging_level = loggin.DEBUG
        else if logging_string == "INFO":
            logging_level = logging.INFO
        else if logging_string == "WARNING":
            logging_level = logging.WARNING
        else if logging_string == "ERROR":
            logging_level = logging.ERROR
        else if logging_string == "CRITICAL":
            logging_level = logging.CRITICAL
    else:
        logging_level = logging.INFO

    logger = logging.getLogger(app_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging_level)

    # Console handler for error output
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging_level)

    # Formatter to make everything look nice
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # Add the handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    return logger
```

And my processing functions look like this:

```
import custom_logging

def do_capture(data_dict_access):
    """Process data"""

    # Custom logging
    LOGGER = custom_logging.create_logger("processor")

    LOGGER.debug("Doing stuff...")
```

However, no matter what the logging environment variable is set to, I still receive debug log messages in the console. Why is my logging level not taking effect, surely the calls to setLevel() should stop the debug messages from being logged?

Comment: First of all: `else if` should be `elif`

Comment: @HaiVu Strange, I'm not getting a syntax error from that. Changed anyway, still no difference

Comment: I posted a solution, but still trying to figure out why your code does not work.

Comment: Try to set your env var to 'INFO' and see if you get an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an easy way to create a logger object:

```
import logging
import os

def create_logger(app_name):
    """Create a logging interface"""
    logging_level = os.getenv('logging', logging.INFO)
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging_level,
        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger(app_name)
    return logger
```

## Discussion

- There is no need to convert from *"DEBUG"* to `logging.DEBUG`, the `logging` module understands these strings.
- Use `basicConfig` to ease the pain of setting up a logger. You don't need to create handler, set format, set level, ... This should work for most cases.

## Update

I found out why your code does not work, besides the `else if`. Consider your line:

```
if logging in os.environ:
```

On this line `loggging` without quote refers to the `logging` library package. What you want is:

```
if 'logging' in os.environ:
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that logging would recognise the strings, that's quite useful. the missing quotes would be what caused the issue, and adding them fixed it.